# Google maps cordova geolocation api not working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I am currently working on an api project and I have to add the geolocation api but it isn't working. When I open the .html file on my browser(Chrome) then it works sort of (its not showing the actual map but it is turning grey and it shows the zoom buttons and everything), but when I run the emulator(via Eclipse) on my Samsung S4 it is not showing anything at all.

In my AndroidManifest file, I have added the `android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS`,
`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

How do I get it to work on my phone and show the map (what am I doing wrong)?

Also in Eclipse, the actual geolocation api is not showing, but when I run command prompt it is already installed, and when I go to windows explorer, to the plugins folder, it shows that it is installed (org.apache.cordova.geolocation), should I just leave it then?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  key=AIzaSyDxYdO_d_hBfeNihd4Ats6ox0ZTIi2I&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var lat;
var lng;

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude         + '<br  />' +
                        'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude        + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude         + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy         + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading          + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed            + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp               + '<br />';
}

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.latitude;


  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    addMarker();
    }

function addMarker() {  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.58, 145.25),
        title: 'Hello World',
        map: map
    });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In function onSuccess(position), when doing:

```
var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
```

Instead of using `geolocation` (which I think you copied from the documentation), you should use the id you defined: `map-canvas`